# Why does my app crash when I add a second user input to be passed to another activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, user-input

I want to pass multiple user inputs to another activity to be displayed. It works fine when it's just one input but as soon as I am trying to add a second user input to the mix my app keeps crashing. I have been browsing questions for a few days on stackoverflow as well as other forums and have tried multiple approaches but none seem to work for me. Thanks for your help in advance! I am pretty new to all this so apologies if the solution is really simple...

This is the code for my first activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.simone.code.MESSAGE";
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE1 = "com.simone.code.NAME";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    public void sendMessage (View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);

        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
        EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);

        String message = editText != null ? editText.getText().toString() : null;
        String name = editName != null ? editName.getText().toString() : null;

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE1, name);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

This is the code for my second activity:

```
public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();

        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        String name = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE1);

        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);

        TextView textView1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        textView1.setText(name);

        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.addView(textView);
        layout.addView(textView1);
    }

}
```

Comment: show your stack trace please

Comment: I got a few error messages. Always says could not find something like class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method com.simone.code.MainActivity.access$super or
class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method com.simone.code.MainActivity.access$super

Answer (score -1, accepted):

***Try That:***

Add those two variables in `DisplayMessageActivity`

```
 public final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.simone.code.MESSAGE";
    public final String EXTRA_MESSAGE1 = "com.simone.code.NAME";
```

and use them directly as following:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras != null) {
   String message = extras.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    String name = extras.getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE1);
//Rst of your code
}
```

Comment: Hey! I tried your solution but it still keeps crashing. As soon as I figure out how to get my stack trace I will post it here. Thanks for your answer - the -1 is not from me.

Comment: @SimonePhoenix try the update and tell me if it works or not

Comment: Just figured it out! I implemented your solution but also took out the layout.addView part of the code at the end. Guess that was messing everything up!

Comment: i am sorry i can't understand you well. is your app still crash or what?

Comment: and if you have two textviews already in your content layout why you use addView again ?

Comment: My app is not crashing anymore. It stopped crashing after I implemented your code suggestion and also deleted the    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.content);
        layout.addView(textView);
        layout.addView(textView1);

Comment: It's working absolutely fine now, thanks for your help! It's been driving me crazy over the last couple days!